# Wi-Fi Channels and devices

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration, wifi-transfer

I am trying to understand the Wi-Fi Channels and how it is been used by devices. The specification says 2.4GHz Wi-Fi has 14 and 5 GHz Wi-Fi has 144 Wi-Fi Channels. My understanding is that each channel is used by each devices being connected to. Does that mean for 2.4 , the maximum possible devices can be 14 and for 5GHz' it is 144 devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My understanding is that each channel is used by each devices being connected to

No. All devices connected to the same access point use the same channel, and share it using [CSMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-sense_multiple_access) (and various other mechanisms – beamforming also plays a part, I think?).

So the number of channels is more relevant to the number of *networks* (well, access points) you want to run. (And it's possible for multiple networks to overlap in their channel usage, but... the more you have, the worse it gets.)

> The specification says 2.4GHz Wi-Fi has 14 and 5 GHz Wi-Fi has 144 Wi-Fi Channels

In theory yes, in practice it doesn't mean much, since it depends on how each country allows those channels to be used. For example, in reality the 2.4 GHz band is limited to channels 1–13 in most places including Europe (ETSI) and just to 1–11 in USA (FCC). Channel 14 is only used in Japan and nowhere else. In the 5 GHz band things vary even more.

Pay attention not just to the number of channels, but also to their spacing. In the 2.4 GHz band, the 20 MHz channels were assigned in a way that most of them overlap each other – this means that in practice, it's as if you only had **three** useful channels in total (1, 6, 11) or maybe four (1, 5, 9, 13).

Also note that modern Wi-Fi specifications use more than just the "standard" 20 MHz channel. For example, in 802.11n you could already have a "40 MHz" mode which combines two 20 MHz channels. (Again, in 2.4 GHz band, this means something like 1+6, 3+8, or 6+11 – *not* 1+2 or 2+3 because those overlap!)

[Here's a table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#5_GHz_(802.11a/h/j/n/ac/ax)) that shows both the country regulations and the 40/80/160 MHz channel modes.